# Go arbitrary query

Tags: go

I am currently trying to execute arbitrary queries using the following (shortened) code

```
func (...) query(...) int {
    rows, err := database.Connection.Query(queryString)
    if err != nil {
        return 1
    }
    columnNames, err := rows.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        return 1
    }
    columns := make([]interface{}, len(columnNames))
    columnPointers := make([]interface{}, len(columnNames))
    for i := range columnNames {
        columnPointers[i] = &columns[i]
    }
    for rows.Next() {
        rows.Scan(columnPointers...)
    }
    log.Println(columns)
    return 0
}
```

However columns holds an slice of byte arrays so I got no idea how can I get the desired result?

Comment: `desired result` means `string`? just do convert.

Comment: If you use the right data types instead of using interfaces, `Scan()` will cast the values properly for you. For example, `var int myCol; rows.Scan(myCol)`